# Problem with the code for fetching data from ether scan

Tags: etherscan, ico, python, external-api

I am trying to fetch ICO data via python from etherscan.io through the API but hitting a problem.

I am using [the code](https://github.com/corpetty/py-etherscan-api) by Corey Petty for python bindings also using his code for ICO analysis

Full code [here](https://pastebin.com/CiYVJyAk).

When I execute `transactions = api.get_all_transactions()`, it just keeps adding pages and never stops until i restart the kernel.

[image]

Please guide.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to the community :) Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to see how to format a post well.